# Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, mono

I have run into this issue and my app wont compile. I was trying to use play services in my app but it was giving me resource not found error I got frustrated and removed all the xamarin files and reinstalled everything. that issue went away now this error has popped up. Any help will be appreciated. P.S I am a beginner in android developer. I have copied some parts of the error below:

```
2>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\\bin\keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keystore "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" 
2>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\\bin\jarsigner.exe -keystore "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg md5withRSA -signedjar bin\Debug\\Messenger.Messenger-Signed-Unaligned.apk C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\projects\test\Messenger\Messenger\obj\Debug\android\bin\Messenger.Messenger.apk androiddebugkey 
2>No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2046-08-06) or after any future revocation date.
2>C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\24.0.1\zipalign.exe 4 "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\projects\test\Messenger\Messenger\bin\Debug\Messenger.Messenger-Signed-Unaligned.apk" "bin\Debug\\Messenger.Messenger-Signed.apk" 
2>:Deployment failed
2>Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.Che`enter code here`ckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<InstallPackage>c__AnonStoreyE.<>m__0(Task`1 t)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
2>The "InstallPackageAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
2>System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<InstallPackage>c__AnonStoreyE.<>m__0(Task`1 t)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
2>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>c__async1.MoveNext()
2>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<StartAsync>c__async0.MoveNext()
2>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
2>   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.InstallPackageAssemblies.Execute()
2>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
2>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
2>---> (Inner Exception #0) Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<InstallPackage>c__AnonStoreyE.<>m__0(Task`1 t)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
2>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>c__async1.MoveNext()
2>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<StartAsync>c__async0.MoveNext()<---
2>
2>Build FAILED.
2>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `adb` to uninstall your app:

```
adb uninstall <your app's package name>
```

This cleans all the leftover Xamarin libraries.

Comment: This worked for me when I was switching between Xamarin Studio on the Mac and Visual Studio running in Windows 10 using Parallels.  The two were sharing the same emulator running on the Mac host.

Answer (score 1):

in android go to

Settings > Applications > All

Remove your app. It might not have the original application name in this list. mine was "com.bla.bla.appname" and was 0.0k in size.