# Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException while debugging

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have two projects in Xamarin Forms A and B, Project B is just a white-labelled version of A. I have also changed all the Project A related dependencies from B. And it was all working fine but all of a sudden I am getting this error that the provider name is the same in both apps, I am not sure what could be causing this as this was working until last week.

> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.package.projb-Dr18A_raYrGiEXYa1lZU9g==: Can't install because provider name dollar_openBracket_applicationId_closeBracket (in package com.package.a) is already used by com.package.proja]
>
> at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName) in E:\A_work\579\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputParsing.cs:line 341
>
> at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass95_0.b__0(Task`1 t) in E:\A_work\579\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 753
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
> ADB0010: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.package.projb-Dr18A_raYrGiEXYa1lZU9g==: Can't install because provider name dollar_openBracket_applicationId_closeBracket (in package com.package.projb) is already used by com.package.proja]
>
> at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName) in E:\A_work\579\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputParsing.cs:line 341
>
> at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass95_0.b__0(Task`1 t) in E:\A_work\579\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 753
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>
> Done building project "ProjectA.Droid.csproj" -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> Deployment failed to Samsung SM-G610F.

I have already tried the following and it's not solving my issue

[Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928756/mono-androidtools-installfailedexception-failure)

[deploy fail Error: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541529/deploy-fail-error-mono-androidtools-installfailedexception-failure-install-fa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by Visual studio 2017 after I added the Firebase Crashlytics!

After reading a couple of threads I realised that it was not a Xamarin bug but moreover something that was caused by Visual studio I am not sure what exactly caused it but, 
After downloading the latest version of VS17 or VS19 I was able to solve the bug!

Feel free to get back if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

From your error, we can infer that you should have used the `ContentProvider` in your app or some specilal library your app refered to.

The authority, as listed in `android:authorities` must be unique.Quoting [the documentation for this attribute](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#auth):

> To avoid conflicts, authority names should use a Java-style naming
>   convention (such as com.example.provider.cartoonprovider). Typically,
>   it's the name of the ContentProvider subclass that implements the
>   provider

Comment: Well, the thing is that the names have always been unique and even now it is and still I am facing this issue for some weird reason. BTW I am aware of this.

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo so that we can test with it?